# Why are are std::allocator's construct and destroy functions deprecated in c++17?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, allocator, c++17

The c++17 specification deprecates the `construct` and `destroy` members of the `std::allocator` object. The working group provided rationale for deprecating other member functions [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html#2.4), under the heading "Deprecate the redundant members of std::allocator".

However they don't mention specifically why those two members are deprecated or what the recommendation is for replacing that functionality. I'm assuming the implication is to use `std::allocator_traits::construct` instead.

I'm a bit confused about whether implementing `construct` may actually still be necessary in some cases though because of [this comment about `std::allocator_traits::construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct)

> Because this function provides the automatic fall back to placement new, the member function construct() is an optional Allocator requirement since C++11.

For custom allocators (e.g. for page-aligned memory using `memalign`), will falling back to placement `new` always produce the correct behavior?

Comment: In fast, they have been removed in C++20.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [allocator requirements table](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements) says that `construct(c, args)`, if provided, must "construct an object of type `C` at `c`".

It says absolutely nothing about 1) what arguments are to be passed to `C`'s constructor or 2) how these arguments are to be passed. That's the allocator's choice, and in fact two allocators in the standard do mess with the arguments before passing them to `C`'s constructor: [`std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor/construct) and [`std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/construct). When constructing a `std::pair`, in particular, the arguments they pass to `pair`'s constructor may not even resemble the ones they received.

There's no requirement to perfectly forward, either; a C++03-style `construct(T*, const T&)` is conforming if inefficient.

`std::allocator`'s `construct` and `destroy` are deprecated because they are useless: no good C++11 and later code should ever call them directly, and they add nothing over the default.

---

Handling memory alignment should be the task of `allocate`, not `construct`.

Comment: I don't understand how are we going to construct an object without using `.construct` and passing the object's construction arguments to it? "std::allocator's construct and destroy are deprecated because they are useless". Again how else are we going to construct the object? By having the allocator inherit from `std::allocator_traits` ?

Comment: Allocator-aware containers must use `allocator_traits::construct`, which defers to the allocator's `construct` if it exists and supplies a default implementation otherwise. Since `std::allocator::construct` uses exactly the default implementation, there's no point in providing it.

Comment: I've read STL container use `std::allocator::construct` to value-initialize their elements. What will they use when in C++20? How will that not break code that use containers with custom allocators (which would e.g. overload `construct`)?

Answer (score 16):

The functions were removed along with others from the paper [D0174R0 Deprecating Vestigial Library Parts in C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html#2.4).  If we look at the relevant section we have

> Many members of std::allocator redundantly duplicate behavior that is otherwise produced by `std::allocator_traits<allocator<T>>`, and could safely be removed to simplify this class. Further, addressof as a free function supersedes `std::allocator<T>::address` which requires an allocator object of the right type. Finally, the reference type aliases were initially provided as an expected means for extension with other allocators, but turned out to not serve a useful purpose when we specified the allocator requirements (17.6.3.5 [allocator.requirements]).
>
> **While we cannot remove these members without breaking backwards compatibility with code that explicitly used this allocator type, we should not be recommending their continued use. If a type wants to support generic allocators, it should access the allocator's functionality through allocator_traits rather than directly accessing the allocator's members** - otherwise it will not properly support allocators that rely on the traits to synthesize the default behaviors. Similarly, if a user does not intend to support generic allocators, then it is much simpler to directly invoke new, delete, and assume the other properties of std::allocator such as pointer-types directly.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So the rational was we do not need to duplicate all of the code in allocator since we have the allocator traits.  If we look at [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) we will see that it does have

```
allocate
deallocate
construct
destroy
max_size
```

static functions so we can use those instead of the ones in the allocator.