# Does the C++ standard guarantee that dynamic allocations are done with new?

Tags: c++, dynamic, standards, new-operator, allocation

simple learning question. Is it specified in the C++ standard how std classes allocate memory? I would assume that internally, all allocations are at some point forwarded to `new` / `new[]`. I'm especially interested in allocations done by containers, std::function and lambdas.

Comment: Standard library containers take an allocator template argument that is used to control how memory is allocated. By default, they use [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

Comment: @jason add what `std::allocator` uses and that is an answer...

Comment: I know that but does the std::allocator allocates with `new` or are there some cases where it doesn't? I know that pushing back on a vector results in a call of `::new` but testing if `new` is called doesn't guarantee that there is no case where `malloc` is used instead.

Comment: @JasonR for your answer, the standard defines the default allocator to: "Remark: the storage is obtained by calling ::operator new(std::size_t) (18.6.2), but it is unspecified when or how often this function is called." found in § D.9.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Standard library containers

Standard library containers take an allocator template argument that is used to control how memory is allocated. By default, they use [`std::allocator<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). `std::allocator<T>` has a member function [`std::allocator<T>::allocate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) that:

> Allocates `n * sizeof(T)` bytes of uninitialized storage by calling `::operator new(std::size_t)`

Likewise, there is a [`std::allocator<T>::deallocate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate) function that calls `operator delete(void *)`.

### `std::function`

`std::function` has [several constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), some of which allow you to specify an allocator object to use for its internal allocations. If you don't specify one, then it will use `std::allocator`.

### Lambdas

I'm not sure what allocations you expect to be done with lambdas. When you declare a lambda, the compiler synthesizes an unnamed functor type behind the scenes that implements the lambda in its `operator()`. If you capture any variables from the local scope, those variables simply become part of that type's definition, increasing the size of the lambda type, but there isn't any dynamic allocation required; the captured variables are just members of the lambda's unnamed type. If you were to assign the lambda to something like a `std::function`, then there could be dynamic allocation done by the `std::function` to accommodate the lambda's increased size.

Comment: The `std::function` constructors taking an allocator as parameter are deprecated, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414610/why-are-are-stdallocators-construct-and-destroy-functions-deprecated-in-c17

Comment: Indeed you're correct. I've never actually used those constructors before myself. What is the alternative in C++17 if you want to specify `std::function`'s allocator?

Answer (score 1):

The classes from the standard library are normally templates and can use a specific allocator for special needs. By default, they use the standard allocator (`std::allocator`) which uses `operator new` and `operator delete`:

> 20.7.9.1 allocator members [allocator.members] 
> ...
>
> ```
> pointer allocate(size_type n, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0);
> ```
>
> ...
> Remark: the storage is obtained by calling ::operator new(std::size_t) (18.6.1), but it is unspecified
>   when or how often this function is called...
>
> ```
> void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n);
> ```
>
> ...
> Remarks: Uses ::operator delete(void*, std::size_t) (18.6.1), but it is unspecified when this
>   function is called.

The fact that it is unspecified when the operators new and delete are called allows implementations to cache unused memory blocks for performance reasons.

Comment: Does that extend to non-templates as well? Containers are only one case which is interesting for me. Another is std::function but I'd like to know if there is a general rule for all std classes.

Comment: Jason already cleared up my missconceptions. I'm relatively new to lambdas and didn't have a look in how they work internally.

Answer (score 1):

The standard containers accept a templated argument that is an allocator.   By default, that allocator for each of the standard containers is of type `std::allocator<T>`   (e.g. the default allocator for a `std::vector<T>` is of type `std::allocator<T>`).   `std::allocator` uses the function `::operator new(size_t)` to allocate raw memory.

Part of the workings of a typical new expression (e.g. of the form `new Type`) is calling the function `::operator new(size_t)`.   However, a default allocator is not required to use such a new expression.

Part of the interface for an allocator is providing a member function `construct(pointer p, const_reference val)`.  This member function of `std::allocate<T>` returns `new((void *)p) T(val)`   (which is sometimes describes as a placement-new expression).

There is no requirement that non-default allocators (e.g. an allocator type supplied by a programmer for use instead of a default allocator) use `::operator new()` or a new expression.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a default allocator is not required to use such a new expression." If the default allocator is `std::allocator<T>`, it is specified to use `::operator new(size_t)` to allocate.

Comment: You're not understanding that an `operator new` function is not a new expression. A new expression like `new X` dynamically constructs a new instance of X by allocating raw memory (e.g. using `::operator new()`) and THEN calling the constructor of `X` to initialise that memory. So a new expression is not just calling `::operator new()`. [It is more complicated than that: an array new expression (like `new X[3]`) calls a different function `::operator new[]()` and then the constructor multiple times. Classes also can overload `operator new` functions (e.g. have an `X::operator new()`]