# i can't find the allocator.destroy() member function in xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode, allocator

I have a MacBook Air and I'm using Xcode as my IDE. When I write the code below, Xcode shows a warning that says "no member named destroy and construct in `std::allocator<int>`". However, when I try to compile the same code in VS Code on my Mac, it builds successfully without any warnings.

```
#include <memory>

int main(){
    std::allocator<int> a;
    int* var = a.allocate(1);
    a.construct(var,10);
    a.destroy(var);
}
```

Please let me know if there are any other issues with the statement that you would like me to address.

[vscode result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylXRZ.png)

[xcode result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7pUa.png)

I'm wondering why the C++ library is not consistent across IDEs, since I assumed it should be the same. Please help me with it, thank you!

---

I changed the C++ language dialect to C++11, and that solved the problem.
[image: solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member functions [`construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) and [`destroy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/destroy) were [deprecated in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39414610/11082165)  and removed in C++20.

Presumably you're using a C++20 compiler in Xcode (hence those member functions are not available) while in  VS Code you're using an older standard.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the C++ language dialect to C++11, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11, you are not supposed to call member functions on an allocator type directly. Instead always go through [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits), which defaults them if they are not explicitly provided by the allocator type:

```
using allocator_traits = std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int>>;

allocator_traits::allocator_type a;

allocator_traits::size_type size = 1;

auto var = allocator_traits::allocate(a, size);
allocator_traits::construct(a, var, 10);
allocator_traits::destroy(a, var);
allocator_traits::deallocate(a, size);
```

`std::allocator`'s `construct` and `destroy` member functions have been removed with C++20 and now also use the defaults provided by `std::allocator_traits` instead, in line with the convention that `std::allocator_traits` is the actual interface to allocators.

Comment: Thank you. I was doing the exam in <C++ Primer>, a book based on C++11. Therefore, I do not know this.

Comment: @pumpkinlion Where in the book is `std::allocator` used in this way? I don't remember it and that seems to be a too advanced topic for an introductory book.

Comment: @pumpkinlion Nevermind, I found the part of the book (section 13.5.). Yes, that's unfortunately out-dated (and was already since C++11 problematic). Normally `std::allocator` is not used directly like that, but I can see why the author decided to introduce it that way. It is simpler and requires less explanation than doing it the correct way. In practice you wouldn't write your own `StrVec` class of course, but just use `std::vector<std::string>`. Writing your own container properly is a bit tricky.